# OLEDB Source running full MDX query when validating

Tags: sql-server, ssis, mdx

I have a pretty heavy MDX query with many dimensions and measurements. I need to export the results of that MDX query to a SQL Server table using SSIS data flow (OLE DB Source --> SQL Command). I created an OLE DB Source, added "Format=Tabular" to its properties, and connected it to the OLE DB Destination. For a simple MDX query it runs fine.

But even for a simple query every time I copy and paste it in the SQL Command window (OLE DB Source) and press "OK" or "Columns" it looks like SSIS runs the whole query and returns the metadata then.

Is it possible to get just metadata without completely executing the query? I need to pass the metadata to the destination. I will appreciate any help on extracting the data from a cube into SQL Server table. Thanks.

Comment: Create your data flow as normal. Edit it until it's correct. Move back to the Control Flow, right click on the Data Flow and under the Properties menu, find `DelayValidation`. Set that to `True` Does this mitigate the problem?

Comment: Thank you, billinkc. This approach works when the query was processed and you already have the metadata in you source. Then you set "Delay Validation" and keep developing. But if I need to change the query in the source and, e.g. add 3 more dimensions to the output, the whole query will be processed, otherwise I will not get extra metadata in the output. I was thinking there is a way to get just metadata without processing the modified query. The approach suggested by Preet Sangha may work.

Answer (score 0):

That's been our experience with SSIS. The way we've got round it is to use a dummy query from a variable, that is returns the metadata to SSIS during design time. Then at runtime the actual variable is modified using another task (such as a script task) to be the full query.